# Error during Vue build: "Locale" is not exported by "vue-i18n" despite correct type import

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm currently facing an issue with my Vue 3 project that integrates vue-i18n. When I attempt to build my project, I encounter the following error:

`[ComponentName].vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang.ts (10:0) "Locale" is not exported by "node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.runtime.esm-bundler.js", imported by "[ComponentName].vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang.ts".`

However, during development, type checks run without any issue and there's no error or warning shown in my IDE. To ensure that I wasn't improperly importing a runtime value, I specifically used import type to import the Locale type from vue-i18n. Here's a snippet of how I imported it:

`import type { Locale } from 'vue-i18n';`

Despite this, the build error persists. This issue is only present during the build phase and not during type checking or development.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insight into why this might be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post your webpack config or your vite.config.js